# Python - Force nan values to get a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I used a mask to work on arrays and now i would like to force "nan" to get a certain value (0 per example...)

A simple example with moderate array, i have :

```
[[[nan, nan], [nan, nan], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]], [[2, 0], [2, 2], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]], [[2, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]]
```

And i would like to get an array as :

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 2], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with [`numpy.nan_to_num`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[np.nan, 0], [1, 2]])
>>> a
array([[ nan,   0.],
       [  1.,   2.]])
>>> a = np.nan_to_num(a)
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

Note that this *creates a new array*, it won't alter the original in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean indexing with `numpy.isnan` on the left-hand-side of an assignment.

```
>>> a
array([[[ nan,  nan],
        [ nan,  nan]],

       [[  2.,   0.],
        [ nan,  nan]],

       [[  2.,   2.],
        [  2.,   0.]]])
>>> a[np.isnan(a)] = 0
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 2.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  0.]]])
>>>
```

Comment: This answer has the advantage of being adaptable to values other than zero, which mine is not.

Comment: I found another, looking through the source, ```np.copyto(a, 0, where = np.isnan(a))``` - which seems comparable time-wise with the boolean indexing.

Comment: ```nan_to_num``` uses the same boolean indexing as this answer for the substitution, as well as substitutions for positive and negative infinity.  It is quite a bit slower probably because of making a copy.